# Lexical analysis of a list

Tags: lexical-analysis

I have to make a lexer for a language that has (among other things) lists of the form `[1,2,3]` for example or `['c','s','q','t']`.

I don't really understand whether I need to match the list at the lexing stage. So, for example would

> 2:[1,2,3];

be

> NUM(2) COLON LSQBRACKET NUM(1) COMMA NUM(2) COMMA NUM(3) RSQBRACKET SEMI

or

> NUM(2) COLON LIST([1,2,3]) SEMI

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it's up to you. If you only ever have to match very simple list literals, then maybe you can get away with treating them kind of like string literals. (But, that's not likely to be a good approach).

You generally want the lexer to output a series of simple tokens. The lexer should be relatively simple -- one rule of thumb is that it should never require recursion.

So, for example, requiring it to output a "LIST" token would be counterproductive -- the lexer would have to recurse on nested lists, meaning that it would implement a mini-parser. Leave that job to the parser.

The first case makes for a simpler lexer, which is still useful to a later-stage parser.